# How to use 2 networks simultanously?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I am trying to connect internet and my corporations network at the same time,I am using one ethernet cable,and one ethernet to usb adapter,and using ubuntu 14.04.

Whenever I try to plug my ethernet cable,the network on the adapter starts not responding.

Here is my route table :

```
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref          Use Iface
    default         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
    192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
    192.168.122.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

and this is my route table after plugging ethernet cable:

```
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    default         10.108.80.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
    10.108.80.0     *               255.255.240.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
    192.168.2.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
    192.168.122.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

I can give more info if you ask .

Comment: I also tried deleting default gateway by sudo route del default gw 192.168.2.1

Comment: If I understand you first output from `route -n` is when is eth cable only in you eth port, and internet work. After that you put cable in your usb ethernet card to access corporate network, second output from `route -n` and you lose internet connection?

Comment: Yes,that is the case

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in default route. When you connect second cable to `usb/eth` your default gateway is changed to gateway from corporate network `10.108.80.1` and packet to "internet" are routed to that router.
If all Corporate network resources on `10.108.80.0 / 255.255.240.0` network you do not need gateway, and simple revert gateway to `192.168.2.1`. You can do that with command

sudo route add default gateway 192.168.2.1

Your packet to *example: 8.8.8.8* will be routed to `192.168.1.1` instead of Corporate gw witch is `10.108.80.1`.

Also you can create script to do this for you.

Example:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/script
```

and put content

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "eth0" ] || exit 0
# put default gw to eth1
route add default dev eth1
```

give `script` privilege

```
chmod 755 /etc/network/if-up.d/script
```

`if-up.d` will trigger script called `script` when `eth0` go `up` and put `default gw` to `eth1`

`eth0` - i guess is card to connect to corporate net.

Comment: I tried your solution,now I can connect to open internet every time,but when I try to connect a url at my corporate network,the browser searches google for url instead

Comment: Set corporate DNS server on first place for internet connection. Request will first go to them then to `8.8.8.8`

Comment: This is not quite correct although it will work most of the time. Every request will only go to _one_ DNS server, and the system may decide which one based on response times. So if the corporate DNS server is faster to reply than Google's, subsequent requests will go _only_ to the corporate server which is able to resolve both corporate and Internet domains. But if the corporate server is slow then requests will go to Google which doesn't know about the corporate machines.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by NetworkManager setting the default route to the corporate network when you connect to it, instead of leaving it on the Internet connection where it belongs.

To prevent that, open the NetworkManager settings for the corporate network connection, go to the "IPv4 Settings" tab, and set the option "use this connection only for resources on its network".